# React Native force close when running on emulator and android device

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react native, first I create a new RN project using "npx react-native init MyTestApp" then start with "npx react-native start" and run it with "npx react-native run-android", the build is successful and the application is installed but the application immediately closes forcefully, I've tried it on the emulator (android 7.0 API 24) and android (Android 4.4.2) but the results are the same...

[image: Start RN]
[image: Run Android]
[image: App Force Close on emulator]

Someone please help me

Comment: can i see App.js screen...

Comment: https://newtextdocument.com/0a2b2172ed  
I haven't changed the code in the RN at all

Comment: as suggest `cmd+adb logcat` check logs and find the exception

Comment: error:
WARNING: linker: libvc1dec_sa.ca7.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmd + adb logcat.

Run it and see what's going on Or you can open Android Studio and check in logcat. 
It will tell us where the triggers are coming from

Comment: error:WARNING: linker: libvc1dec_sa.ca7.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.

Comment: The error was about the build.gradle configuration file but it was too old, I think the current new version of React-native has fixed it.
I tried to re-init the project with your manipulations and it worked.
You need to try initialize the project and run it again.

Comment: I've tried several times to make a new project but it's still the same, is there another way? @Thanh Cao

Answer (score 0):

first run the `npx react-native run-android` command after the build is successful if the bundle is not loaded then run `npx react-native start` it will start loading the app bundle